How does Gaze of Two Minds interact with Misty Step?
Gaze of the Two Minds has received a significant upgrade. In addition to gaining the special senses of a creature, you can now cast spells as if you were in their space:

You can use a bonus action to touch a willing creature and perceive through its senses until the end of your next turn...
While perceiving through the other creature’s senses, you benefit from any special senses possessed by that creature, and you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space if the two of you are within 60 feet of each other.

The mechanics are straightforward for line-of-sight spells, but a bit ambiguous for teleportation spells. For example, the effects of Misty Step are described as follows:

Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see.

Notably, it does not explicitly say "you teleport from your current location." This leaves room to argue that RAW, Misty Step, when cast from the space of a creature 60 feet away, would teleport the caster to an unoccupied, visible location up to 90 feet away.
RAW, how does Gaze of Two Minds actually interact with Misty Step?

Yes, you could teleport 90 feet* in that case
Although really, you are casting the spell as if you were in the other creature's space, and Misty Step is teleporting you 30 feet from that location. The end result is still that you end up 90 feet from your previous location though.

you can cast spells as if you were in your space or the other creature’s space

If you were in the other creature's space, could you use Misty Step to reach the target destination? If so, you can use Misty Step with Gaze of Two Minds to reach that location.
The way to check if you can do something using Gaze of Two Minds is:

Check if you can cast a spell to accomplish the thing if you cast from your own space. If so, you can cast the spell and do the thing.
Imagine you were in the other creature's space. Check if you could then cast the spell to accomplish the thing. If so, you can cast the spell and do the thing.

In this case, you could clearly (if you were in the other creature's space) teleport to the intended destination using Misty Step, so you can do so with Gaze of Two Minds + Misty step.
Note:
I have assumed "or" in the quoted rule is an exclusive or and not an inclusive or. Reading it as an inclusive or would yield the same results in this case, but would also permit you to cast a spell as if you were in both spaces, such as if you had vision from only one space but met distance requirements from only the other. If you want answers about edge cases which rely on this distinction, I think it would be best to ask a separate follow up question.

You cast it from their space, but why isn't there still a 30ft from self restriction? The casting location doesn't become self, or does it?

If you were in the creature's space, the destination would be within 30 feet of you. You would be obeying the restriction if you were in the creature space, and you count as in the creature space. It doesn't say anything about "treat the creature space as the origin of the spell" or "count range from the creature's space". You count as if you are there for ALL purposes.
I purposely left any discussion of range/self/targeting/etc. out of my answer because it's just a distraction. The two step process I outlined is the full process you need to use to understand Gaze of Two Minds.

Isn’t this answer the same as nonymous's?

Saying the same thing, maybe saying it in a better way. Upvote.

@Tarod I don't consider them equivalent, which is why I have not yet downvoted this.  The other answer may (not sure) have reached a correct conclusion, but I consider the reasoning behind it to be faulty.

(I am often unpersuaded by "general/specific" arguments when I can't easily tell what the specificity principle is.)

Your two step "way to check" either does not include the case where misty step is permissible by distance from only one space and permissible by vision only from the other space, or implicitly assumes that this would not be possible.  Would such a case work?

@Kirt I have indeed assumed that "or" here means "exclusive or", i.e., you are in your space or the creature's space, but not both, because that's the weaker assumption and all that's needed to answer this question. In English, "or" can sometimes be an "inclusive or" and is equivalent to "and/or". A second question might dive into this case more deeply. While I strongly suspect it's exclusive or (so only if you could fully cast from one of the spaces, meeting some requirements from each does not work), I honestly don't have supporting evidence to back that up specific to 5e.

@Kirt I have edited in a note to the answer itself with the same information. I think that's a separate question from this one, but you are right I should clarify the assumption I was working under.

Nicely done. +1

If Misty Step has a casting time of a Bonus Action, and you need your Bonus Action to maintain Gaze of Two Minds, how is the interaction possible?

@Tarod Most directly, Gaze of Two minds lasts from the turn you cast it until the END of your next turn. Even if you choose not to extend it on your next turn, you could cast Misty Step on that turn. I don't have extensive knowledge of the new 2024 rules, but I suspect there will be other ways to accomplish it as well as we get new class features, magic items, rules, etc.

@stevenjackson121 True! Depending on the scenario, this combo is possible. Thanks for replying!

Gaze of Two Minds has only minor effects on Misty Step
The range of Misty Step is self. This doesn't benefit from measuring from the other character's location, since your self is still your self, and you can't teleport from their position because you're not actually there. The destination of your teleport must still be within 30 feet of your starting position.
However, the vision you gain through the eyes of the target of Gaze of Two Minds might make some positions within Misty Step's normal range visible to you, where they were not previously. For example, if the creature whose senses you're sharing has darkvision and you do not, you could teleport into a completely darkened area, if it's within their darkvision's range. Or you may be able to teleport to the other side of a wall or other obstacle, if the other creature can see behind it while you cannot.

Gaze of Two Minds effectively increases Misty Step's reach by 60 feet
This is a case of "specific beats general", and Gaze of Two Minds is more specific than Misty Step. Gaze of Two Minds specifies a new effect on spells. Just as with emanation spells, or any or spells requiring a clear path to the target, Misty Step is cast as though in the space of the perceiving creature. The caster is "briefly surrounded by silvery mist" and teleported "up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space they can see" through the Gaze of two Minds.

This answer could be improved by explaining why the one is more specific than the other.  I'm not seeing it.  Arguably, being confined to a single origin is more specific than having two to choose from.

I’m not convinced by this either. “You teleport up to 30 feet” seems to pretty specifically say you teleport from where you are to a space up to 30 feet away from you. The familiar surely just helps with being able to see the end point?
